# How to make the session expire after a browser close in node.js with express?

Tags: session, node.js, express

I am using

```
req.session.cookie.maxAge = 14 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 : 0
```

to let the session expire after two weeks. but now I want to make it expire after a browser close. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [connect session middleware docs](https://github.com/expressjs/session#reqsessioncookie): "we can set `req.session.cookie.expires` to `false` to enable the cookie to remain for only the duration of the user-agent."

Answer (score -2):

Use session cookies instead of specifying an age.