# Node.js detect user online or not

Tags: node.js, session, cookies

I'm using Node.js to implement a system to detect the user is online no not.

Here is the way I'm using:

1. Set every user's default session MaxAge to 30 seconds
2. Let each user sends the server a signal to prolong their session every 20 seconds.
3. Once they come offline and stop sending signals, their sessions expire.

However, I found another post on stackoverflow says that to detect the user offline, we can do:

```
req.session.cookie.expires = false;
```

Then the session will automatically expire once the user close the browser???

[How to make the session expire after a browser close in node.js with express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992022/how-to-make-the-session-expire-after-a-browser-close-in-node-js-with-express)

Can anyone tell me if this is a correct solution? Thank you!

Comment: No, this depends on browser and is not reliable ( from backend point of view session will never expire ). Your solution is good, almost as good as possible ( it can only be better if you use WebSockets ).

Comment: As long as your server, both Node and your session provider, can handle the onslaught of users just sending a heartbeat/ping, it's a common pattern. You could also just record a timestamp of last seen and use that as a filter for who is active rather than constantly expiring and recreating sessions.