# Trying to display different nav items based on if a user is logged in

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, handlebars.js

I am trying to set up an site so that when a user is logged in, the nav bar will display "logout", and if the user isn't logged in, then it will display "signup" and "login". Right now through insomnia I have tested that the login works properly and hits the route. The handlebars just doesn't seem to update based on whether session is loggedIn or not. Any help is much appreciated, and please let me know if you need anymore info on anything.

```
 {{#if loggedIn}}
            <button class="button is-light" id="logout">logout</button>
 {{else}}
            <a href="http://localhost:3001/signup" class="button is-primary"> <strong>Sign up</strong> </a>
            <a href="http://localhost:3001/login"class="button is-light"> <strong>Log in</strong> </a>
 {{/if}}
```

This is the route set up for user login

````
```router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
`try {
const userData = await User.findOne({
  where: {
    email: req.body.email
  }
})`

if (!userData) {
  res.status(400).json({ message: "Incorrect email or password."});
  return;
}

const validPassword = await userData.checkPassword(req.body.password)

if (!validPassword) {
  console.log("YO")
  res.status(400).json({ message: "Incorrect email or password."})
  return;
}

req.session.save(() => {
  req.session.user_id = userData.id;
  req.session.loggedIn = true;

  res.json({ user: userData, message: 'You are now logged in!' });
});
````

`} catch (err) { res.status(400).json(err)} })`

And lastly this is the code server.js code showing using the session data

````
    const sess = {
    secret: 'Super secret secret',
    cookie: {},
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new SequelizeStore({
    db: sequelize
    })
    };

    app.use(session(sess)); ```

SCRIPT FOR LOGIN PAGE
    const loginFormHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    console.log("YO!!!!")

    const email = document.querySelector('#email-login').value.trim();
    const password = document.querySelector('#password-login').value.trim();
  
    if (email && password) {
      const response = await fetch('/api/users/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({email, password }),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      });
  
      if (response.ok) {
        // If successful, redirect the browser to the profile page
        document.location.replace('/');
      } else {
        alert(response.statusText);
      }
    }
  };
````

Comment: It looks like your login happens via an XMLHttpRequest. What is not clear is if your Handlebars template is rendered on the client or on the server. If it is on the client, then you will need to re-render once you get your login API response. If it is on the server, this is a little more tricky because you would need to make a full HTTP request to the server to have your template render again.

Comment: It is done client side and I realize that I forgot to include the script for the login form itself where the location is redirected back to the homepage, I have just added it.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you shared the code that renders the template - a template function invocation or a `res.render` call.

Comment: Sorry the res.render call is made
 router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("home")
})
home is where the #if loggedIn in the template is, so if the login response is ok, then it is replaced to localhost:3001/

Comment: That's a server-side render. You will need to access the `loggedIn` state that is stored in the session and pass the value to the `res.render` call. See: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render

Comment: sorry I'm trying to follow this syntax but am really confused as to how I would do that. Would it be something like 
res.render ('home', {loggedIn: req.session.loggedIn)}

Comment: Yes, that looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem, and now the logout button shows up. However, now everytime I start it back up, it assumes I am always logged in. How would you go about dealing with that as well?

Comment: The user will remain logged-in until the session expires. So you need to change the session expiry. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6992022/3397771

Comment: I am struggling with understanding where this would be added and the exact syntax for it to work. Where am I added in req.session.cookie.expires= false;

Also just wanted to say thank you so much for taking the time to help, I greatly appreciate it